# Is it possible to change to byte size or width and height of an image before uploading to the server?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Is there a way to change the byte size of the file?  For example, below I'm checking to see if the file size that's being uploaded is > than a max size (variable coming from backend).

I've seen examples online that use `canvas` but I don't want to use that.  Below, my attempt doesn't seem to be working.

Is it possible for me to change the image's dimensions (before the `if()` statement) so that naturally the MB will decrease as well? (width and height) before uploading to the server?

I've tried a lot of ways but have ran out options.

```
function fileValidationWinnerPhoto() {
    const realFileBtn = document.getElementById("real-file");
    let filePath = realFileBtn.value;
    let maxSize = size * 1000000; // 10MB
    
    realFileBtn.files[0].size = 2097152;

    if(realFileBtn.files[0].size > maxSize) {
        console.log(realFileBtn.files[0].size);

        fileSizeErrorModal.style.display = "block";
        attachEventListenerToFileSizeErrorModal(customButtonFileSize, fileSizeErrorModal)
        realFileBtn.value = '';
        return false;
    } else {
        fileAcceptedFlag = true;
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the canvas solution?

Comment: [The `File` `.size` property is non-writable](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-size). What were you trying to achieve with `realFileBtn.files[0].size = 2097152;`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Node? You could use Sharp
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. Notice the object ``document``, which only exists in the browser. And, he's asking about changing the width and height of an image before submission to the server.